# How to change Eclipse Oxygen Dark Theme Still Show White Scrollbar Gutters on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, macos-sierra

Excitedly, I downloaded the latest Eclipse Oxygen and wanted to try out its Dark Theme.

However, the scrollbar gutters are still white, which clashes with the theme and is simply distracting.

I am on a MacOS. How do I change it to match the theme?

Here is a picture of what I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't happen when scroll bars are set to show automatically.

Comment: My "Show scroll bar" setting is set to "Automatically based on mouse or trackbad". Is that what you are talking about? If so, it's still a problem nevertheless. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah! I changed to "When scrolling" and the gutters turned to a dark color. That should work... assuming it's not going to mess up my regular experience elsewhere really bad. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of annoying everywhere else as now there is no indication that scrollbars are there more content exists. Is there a way for Eclipse to change the color of those gutters? IntelliJ does it. Why can't Eclipse?